# how filter model1 has_many model2 has_one model3 (polymorphic)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have model **User**, then

```
has_many :estates, dependent: :destroy
```

Model **Estate** with polymorphic association

```
has_one :location, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
```

in **Location** migration, i have

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :locations do |t|
t.string :address
t.decimal :lat, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
t.decimal :lng, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
t.references :locatable, polymorphic: true, index: true
```

How i can filter or find **Users** from Location.address? 
I tried

```
User.where(estates: { location: { address: "London" } })
```

and have this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: estates.locatable_id:        
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "estates"."locatable_id" = '-   
--
:address: !ruby/object:Arel::Nodes::BindParam {}'
```

Maybe something like

```
User.includes(:estates).where
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does a `RealEstate` come in? Are `Estates` and `RealEstates` the same thing or different?

Comment: i'm sorry for typo. Yes, it's the same. I'm update post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is using a join to find users.

```
User.joins(estates: :location).where(locations: {address: "London"})
```

This tells your sql call to match users to estates and estates to locations and to select only the users where the location is "London".

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: location.address: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "estates" ON "estates"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."locatable_id" = "estates"."id" AND "locations"."locatable_type" = ? WHERE "location"."address" = 'London'

Comment: Sorry, the contents of the where clause should have been .where(locations: {address: "London"}) instead of .where(location: {address: "London"}).  I've updated my answer